# OpenCSV not escaping the quotes(")

Tags: java, regex, csv, opencsv

I have a CSV file which will have delimiter or unclosed quotes inside a quotes, How do i make CSVReader ignore the quotes and delimiters inside quotes.
For example:

```
123|Bhajji|Maga|39|"I said Hey|" I am "5|'10."|"I a do "you"|get that"
```

This is the content of file.

The below program to read the csv file.

```
@Test
public void readFromCsv() throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(
            "/home/netspurt/awesomefile.csv");
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-8");
    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(isr, '|', '\"');

    for (String[] row; (row = reader.readNext()) != null;) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
    }
    reader.close();
    isr.close();
    fis.close();
}
```

I get the o/p something like this.

```
[123, Bhajji, Maga, 39, I said Hey| I am "5|'10., I am an idiot do "you|get that]
```

what happened to quote after `you`

Edit:
The Opencsv dependency
    
        com.opencsv
        opencsv
        3.4

Comment: which OpenCSV are you using? com.opencsv:opencsv / au.com.bytecode:opencsv / net.sf.opencsv:opencsv ?

Comment: @RemigiusStalder: Please see now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the CSV format specifies the quotes(") if its inside a field we need to precede it by another quote("). So this solved my problem.

```
123|Bhajji|Maga|39|"I said Hey|"" I am ""5|'10."|"I a do ""you""|get that"
```

Refrence: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt

Answer (score 3):

from the source code of com.opencsv:opencsv:

```
  /**
     * Constructs CSVReader.
     *
     * @param reader    the reader to an underlying CSV source.
     * @param separator the delimiter to use for separating entries
     * @param quotechar the character to use for quoted elements
     * @param escape    the character to use for escaping a separator or quote
     */

    public CSVReader(Reader reader, char separator,
                     char quotechar, char escape) {
        this(reader, separator, quotechar, escape, DEFAULT_SKIP_LINES, CSVParser.DEFAULT_STRICT_QUOTES);
    }
```

see http://sourceforge.net/p/opencsv/source/ci/master/tree/src/main/java/com/opencsv/CSVReader.java

There is a constructor with an additional parameter escape which allows to escape separators and quotes (as per the javadoc).

Comment: Well if i put both quotechar and escape as ' \" ' it gives me an exception both cannot be same

Comment: try to make it a backslash, as in CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(isr, '|', '\"', '\\');

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have mentioned the result of the processing you get. But what is the result you want to achieve? Same splits but with the quote between you and |? Or different splitting? To be honest, this looks like a bug in CSVParser, as it should either treat quotes as field delimiter or leave them as is, which is both not the case for the swallowed quote between you and |.

Comment: I have isolated the missing quote to two simple cases: 1: ["I "y"|h"] and 2: ["I"y"|h"] (the square brackets should be removed). The second one just without the space after I - which strangely swallows even both quotes around the y. Each of these corner cases should imho - with current interpretation of the default parameters - parse to one single field identical to the input line.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I don't have enough rep to add a comment so I will have to add an answer.

For your original question of what happened to the quote after the you the answer is the same as what happened to the quote before the I.

For CSV data the quote immediately before and after the separator is the start and end of the field data and is thus removed.  That is why those two quotes are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this was available eight years ago, but OpenCSV has an option to `ignoreQuotations`.

```java
private final CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParserBuilder()
            .withIgnoreQuotations(true)
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to escape out the quotes that are part of the field.  The default escape character is the \

Taking a guess as to which quotes you want to escape the string should look like

```
123|Bhajji|Maga|39|"I said \"Hey I am \"5'10. Do \"you\" get that?\""
```